# Does Android OS for Mobile Phones share the same code base with Android Things?

Tags: android, android-things

Do they share the code base and version number?

Does *Google* release the same piece of code for both and just use different flags for mobile phones and *Android Things*?

This may be a strange question, as I am particularly interested in *Android Application Framework*.

Answer (score 1):

> Do they share the code base and version number?

From an *Android* application developers's view point there is not much difference between *Android* OS and *Android Things*. I.e. you can successfully deploy an Android app developed for *Android* (OS version 7+) on a platform running *Android Things*.

> Does *Google* release the same piece of code for both and just use different flags for mobile phones and *Android Things*?

No "flags" at all. It's rather a matter of adding new system (*C/C++/Java*) services specific to the [supported platforms](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms) with its underlying hardware or removing the old ones, needed for mobile devices and not related to embedded systems. Actually *Android Things* is pretty much an inheritor of [Brillo](https://android.googlesource.com/brillo/manifest).

As a quick look consider the following [overview of *Android Things* OS](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html) to see how it differs from *Android*.

Comment: Considering the resource constraints of embedded systems, I suppose believe there should be a "lite" version of Android Application Framework that is installed in every Android IoT device. Incorrect?

Comment: @Infinite, _"I suppose believe there should be a "lite" version of Android Application Framework"_. I'd rather say a "heavy" one, not "lite". Moreover, there is no difference between an _Android Things_ and a regular _Android_ app unless the first one uses APIs for interacting with the underlying hardware (GPIOs, SPI, I2C etc.) In fact, you can deploy an _Android_ app developed for the OS version 7+ on an _Android Things_ running platform.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the Android Application Framework, you can expect the vast majority of APIs to be the same on Android phones and Android Things. Specifically, [this page](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html) details the APIs that are not available:

- CalendarContract
- ContactsContract
- DocumentsContract
- DownloadManager
- MediaStore
- Settings
- Telephony
- UserDictionary
- VoicemailContract

Additionally, a few Google Play Service APIs are not available.

In terms of whether Google releases "the same piece of code for both" the answer is a bit complicated. Android's framework is a combination of a lot of files, some of which only make sense for specific form factors. Different build configurations state what files to include, which to not include, and how exactly to build the correct system image.